# Looking for a non-profit / freeware software license

Tags: windows, licensing

I am currently looking for license agreement e.g. GNU, that declares a software free for everyone and the software itself will not be used for any monetary gain / profit. Although the software can't be modified.

Could someone please point me in the right direction

Many thanks

Comment: You could look at the [Creative Commons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons_licenses) family of licenses, there are a number of combinations possible. Perhaps the combination "nc nd" is what you need: non-commercial use, and no derivative works.

Comment: It's pointless specifying license conditions you have no possible way of enforcing.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth I wouldnt be to sure of that ;)

Comment: @Neil, it you don't specify license conditions, you have no possible way of enforcing them. :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're looking for a 'Free For non commercial Use' license. You could take a look at the Creative Commons licenses. That's the licence also used for media files on Wikipedia, but I can imagine it can apply to software too.

Comment: They don't recommend using their licences for software http://wiki.creativecommons.org/FAQ#Can_I_use_a_Creative_Commons_license_for_software.3F